# getRange Not Referencing Correctly from Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a new join in StackOverflow and new programming. Please bear with me hehe.

Ok, let's start with my question. I was started to write Google sheet Script and This Script below:

```
var data = activesheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 3).getValue();
```

Normally it should have a return value since row 1 column 1 to row 1 column 3 right?  but after opened Log for look data, the result has the return just data of row 1 column 1 only. why it does not show data of row 1 column 2 and row 1 column 3.

I was copied script form this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5TbN36E8Uw

Comment: `activesheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 3)` means the range of "A1:C1" of `activesheet`. In your script, `getValue()` is used. By this, only value of "A1" is retrieved. When you want to retrieve the values from the range of "A1:C1", how about modifying `getValue()` to `getValues()`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) But I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike. Thank a lots for your support Now the problem can fixed hehe

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `activesheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 3).getValue()` will return the value from the `A1` cell since `getRange(1, 1, 1, 3)` will return the range `A1:C1` and the `getValue()` method will return the first value of this range.

If you want to retrieve the `values` from your selection you should use `getValues()` instead of `getValue()`.

**Reference**

- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).